# How to see picture of a graph?

Tags: graph, graphics

does any body know how to show a graph?
by a graph I mean connectivity graph and by showing it I mean see a picture of it while you have it's adj list.

UPD 1 : by see ing a picuter of it I mean does any body know any kjnd of website or app that it get graph adj list as an input and give us picture of that graph as an output ?!

Answer (score 2):

tikz http://graphviz.org/ example http://graphs.grevian.org/example

dot http://www.texample.net/

graph-easy http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/lib/Graph/Easy.pm

Many other programs
or normal in any script language